# Flex Grid not rendering in Orchard CMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I dont understand why Flex Grid is not rendering in my orchard cms project. same code is running in separate project but does not work here.  below is the code for page. i have verified the path for scripts and style sheet and both are correct.

**View**

@{

```
Script.Include("navigation-admin.js");
Script.Require("jQuery");
Script.Require("jQueryUI");
Script.Require("flexgrid");

Style.Include("flexgrid.css");
Style.Include("flexgrid.pack.css");
}

<table id="jobListing" style="display: none"></table>

@using (Script.Foot()) { 

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#jobListing').flexigrid({
            url: '/Member/List',
            dataType: 'json',
            colModel: [
                {
                    display: 'Caption',
                    name: 'Caption',
                    width: 180,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left'
                }, {
                    display: 'Name',
                    name: 'Name',
                    width: 180,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left'
                }, ]
        });
    });        

</script>

}
```

**ResourceManifest**

```
    public void BuildManifests(ResourceManifestBuilder builder)
    {
        // Create and add a new manifest
        var manifest = builder.Add();


        manifest.DefineScript("flexgrid").SetUrl("flexigrid.pack.js", "flexigrid.js");        
    }
```

Currently showing

[image]

Should show layout like this (not data or columns)

[image]

**Console Errors**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move your `$('#jobListing').flexigrid({ .. });` to the document ready part.

Also, to give you some tips:

1. You should add your scripts and styles to the ResourceManifest
2. If your don't use the ResourceManifest, use `Script.Include("PathToScript")` instead
3. You should use `Script.Require("jQuery")` instead of requiring it yourself (it probably is injected twice)
4. I don't think there is a section called Scripts in Orchard. Use the following instead:

@using (Script.Foot()) {

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {

        [.....your code here.....]
    });
    //]]>

</script>
```

}

**EDIT:**

Looking at your console errors, I'd say you miss the web.config in the Scripts and Styles folder.

"By default, Orchard is setup to restrict folder permissions. This is usually overriden by adding a web.config to each folder as required (in this case, your scripts folder).

If you use the codegen module to generate your module, then this is done for you as part of the generation. If not, then you need to add the web.config yourself."

source: [Orchard CMS : Javascript file returns 404 not found even though it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720481/orchard-cms-javascript-file-returns-404-not-found-even-though-it-exists)

Comment: Please see the modified code as per your suggestion but still it does not work.

Comment: When using the ResourceManifest you have to use the `Script.Require()` method. For manually including you can use `Script.Include()`

Comment: Thanks it worked but its not picking up style properly i guess.

Comment: I have modified the code to show only two columns. it shows up but style is not working. i have attached both image files. first is my grid which is showing two columns without layout. second one is original flexgrid project which shows up proper layout.

Comment: Are your scripts properly loaded? And in the correct sequence? Any console errors?

Comment: ooops! there are errors i just checked in chrome console. please see the attached file

Comment: web.config is there in both folders

Comment: shouldnt flexgrid.css be flexigrid.css? Same for flexgrid.pack.css

Comment: Thanks buddy. it worked. you are genius. i have another issue but i will post it in another thread.